# How do I fix "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature" in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am trying to follow a tutorial and I am stuck on a compiler error because it is expecting a standard class with a constructor, but in the tutorial this is how it was done. Maybe things have changed since the tutorial was release, but I can't get a hold of the person who created the tutorial.  i would like to finish it.

The Error message that I am getting:

"Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."

I am new to angular please help me out.

bookstore-front/src/app/book-detail/book-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Book } from '../service/model/Book';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BookService } from '../service/api/book.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-book-detail',
  templateUrl: './book-detail.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private book: Book = new Book();

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .map(params => params['bookId'])
      .switchMap(id => this.bookService.getBook(id))
      .subscribe(book => this.book = book);
  }

  delete() {
    this.bookService.deleteBook(this.book.id)
      .finally(() => this.router.navigate(['/book-list']))
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

bookstore-front/src/app/service/model/Book

```
 /**
 * BookStore APIs
 * BookStore APIs exposed from a Java EE back-end to an Angular front-end
 *
 * OpenAPI spec version: 1.0.0
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.
 * https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */


/**
 * Book resourse representation.
 */
export interface Book {
    /**
     * Identifier
     */
    id?: number;
    /**
     * Title of the book
     */
    title: string;
    /**
     * Summary describing the book
     */
    description?: string;
    /**
     * Unit cost
     */
    unitCost?: number;
    /**
     * ISBN number
     */
    isbn: string;
    /**
     * Date in which the book has been published
     */
    publicationDate?: Date;
    /**
     * Number of pages
     */
    nbOfPages?: number;
    /**
     * URL of the image cover
     */
    imageURL?: string;
    /**
     * Language in which the book has been written
     */
    language?: Book.LanguageEnum;
}
export namespace Book {
    export type LanguageEnum = 'ENGLISH' | 'FRENCH' | 'SPANISH' | 'PORTUGUESE' | 'ITALIAN' | 'FINISH' | 'GERMAN' | 'DEUTSCH' | 'RUSSIAN';
    export const LanguageEnum = {
        ENGLISH: 'ENGLISH' as LanguageEnum,
        FRENCH: 'FRENCH' as LanguageEnum,
        SPANISH: 'SPANISH' as LanguageEnum,
        PORTUGUESE: 'PORTUGUESE' as LanguageEnum,
        ITALIAN: 'ITALIAN' as LanguageEnum,
        FINISH: 'FINISH' as LanguageEnum,
        GERMAN: 'GERMAN' as LanguageEnum,
        DEUTSCH: 'DEUTSCH' as LanguageEnum,
        RUSSIAN: 'RUSSIAN' as LanguageEnum
    }
}
```

If I try to change 
private book: Book = new Book();

to

private book: Book;

I get this error

```
BookFormComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Object.eval (BookFormComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

Comment: you should write this : ```private book: Book ;```

Comment: Does that initialize the object?

Comment: this make a book object with type Book for initialize you should do something like this: ```private book: Book = {title: 'title' , isbn: 'isbn' , ... }```

Comment: My back end just broke, I need to fix that. Then I will try just defining the book like you stated.

Comment: replace import statement with this. `import  Book  from '../service/model/Book';` this might help you

Comment: @fatemefazli, I get a new error I don't instantiate the book, but if I instantiate the object with all the members as null it ran fine.  Why do you think the tutorial has a constructor there?

Comment: I am thinking he must have changed the Book to be a class instead of an interface.  What are the draw backs in doing so?

Comment: His tutorial is also lacking an example of file uploads.  I am using a javaee back end. Does anyone know of any good tutorials which include an example of uploading and saving a file in a database using angular and java ee?

Comment: is if you need/wish to create an instance of perhaps a custom object, whilst getting the benefits of type-checking things such as arguments, return types or generics - a class makes sense. If you’re not creating instances - we have interfaces at our disposal, and their benefit comes from not generating any source code, yet allowing us to somewhat “virtually” type-check our code. yes tutorial is using javaee standards in angular but it's a little bit different .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is if you need/wish to create an instance of perhaps a custom object, whilst getting the benefits of type-checking things such as arguments, return types or generics - a class makes sense. If you’re not creating instances - we have interfaces at our disposal, and their benefit comes from not generating any source code, yet allowing us to somewhat “virtually” type-check our code.yes tutorial is using javaEE standards in angular but it's a little bit different you can write your interface this way:

```
interface Book {
    id?: number;
    title: string;
    description?: string;
    unitCost?: number;
    isbn: string;
    publicationDate?: Date;
    nbOfPages?: number;
    imageURL?: string;
    language?: Book.LanguageEnum;
}
type LanguageEnum = 'ENGLISH' | 'FRENCH' | 'SPANISH' | 'PORTUGUESE' | 'ITALIAN' | 'FINISH' | 'GERMAN' | 'DEUTSCH' | 'RUSSIAN';
const LanguageEnum = {
        ENGLISH: 'ENGLISH' as LanguageEnum,
        FRENCH: 'FRENCH' as LanguageEnum,
        SPANISH: 'SPANISH' as LanguageEnum,
        PORTUGUESE: 'PORTUGUESE' as LanguageEnum,
        ITALIAN: 'ITALIAN' as LanguageEnum,
        FINISH: 'FINISH' as LanguageEnum,
        GERMAN: 'GERMAN' as LanguageEnum,
        DEUTSCH: 'DEUTSCH' as LanguageEnum,
        RUSSIAN: 'RUSSIAN' as LanguageEnum
    }
export{
    Book,
    LanguageEnum,
    LanguageEnum
}
```

import everyone you need and use them, for using interface:

```
import { Book } from '../service/model/Book'; 

private book: Book = {title: 'title' , isbn: 'isbn' , ... }
```

and it's no need to convert it to class.